# Sockets not responding with FLASK

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to add **sockets** to a simple **FLASK** app in order to add a real time chat .

The **problem** that is no socket connection is established ( no socket requests are shown in terminal nor JS log messages neither errors in console )

**related JS code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log("Test");
        socket.send('User has connected !');

    }); 

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log('Received message');
        $("#messages").append('<li>'+msg+'</li>');

    });

    $('#sendbutton').on('click', function() {
        console.log("message sent");
        socket.send($('#myMessage').val());
        $('#myMessage').val('');
    }); 

});
```

**related python code :**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="*")   
@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    print('Message : ' , msg)
    send(msg,broadcast=True)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.secret_key='secret123'
    socketio.run(app,debug=True) 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('Home.htm')

#and other routes..
```

**PIP freeze output**

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.6.1
click==7.1.2
configparser==3.5.0b2
cryptography==2.6.1
cycler==0.10.0
dbus-python==1.2.12
entrypoints==0.3
enum34==1.1.6
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-MySQLdb==0.2.0
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
gyp==0.1
ipaddress==1.0.17
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
keyring==18.0.1
keyrings.alt==3.1.1
kiwisolver==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==2.2.3
mysqlclient==1.4.6
numpy==1.16.6
olefile==0.46
pandas==0.24.2
passlib==1.7.2
Pillow==6.1.0
pycrypto==2.6.1
PyGObject==3.34.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
pyxdg==0.25
scipy==1.2.3
SecretStorage==2.3.1
six==1.12.0
subprocess32==3.5.4
Werkzeug==1.0.1
WTForms==2.3.1
```

**in terminal ,Only HTTP requests are being made**

[image]

It's **IMPORTANT** to mention that everything works perfectly when running an html page using **LIVE SERVER** ( VS CODE extension ) on port 5500 apart from the back-end server working on port 5000. Surely , that's useless in this case because it's not possible to run a live server inside templates within FLASK framework environment .

How to make that work **properly** in this case ? THANKS !

Comment: Can you add the output of the `pip freeze` command to your question?

Comment: @Miguel post edited

Comment: When you say that you don't see a "socket" connection, did you mean "WebSocket"? Do you at least see HTTP connections constantly being made to the `/socket.io` endpoint?

Comment: @Miguel no socket connection is identified , However , HTTP connections are being made normally to the roots i created , check the edited post for whats in terminal . thanks  very much

Answer (score 0):

Is it working now? It seems Werkzeug 1.0.1 supports websockets, but you need to provide a rule based on their docs to enable it: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/routing/. Do you have that configured?

I had a similar issue while doing a chat app recently, and resolved it by using gunicorn, with reference to the docs: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: i am actually using WSGI server , please check the edited question for more informations , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although no error was shown , i discovered i didn't add a CDN to html for socket.io.min.js .
Now that works fine , still confused why no error of unresolved reference has appeared.